# API Data using R

Tags: r, api, weather

I am using below code to get weather data from 1st Jan 2016 till March 2016 however, I am getting only one month of data ie march. Not sure what's going wrong here. thanks for the help.

For token I have put imaginary xyx for security and privacy concerns so if someone wants to run the code you'll have to get a new token with ur email.

```
    base <- 'https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/data?'
    datasetid='datasetid=GHCND'
    stationid = '&stationid=GHCND:ASN00087036'
    startd= '&startdate=2016-02-01'
    endd= '&enddate=2016-03-31'
    lmt = '&limit=1000'
    tok = 'xyz'
    url <- paste0(base,datasetid,stationid,startd,endd,lmt)
    
    a <-  GET(url,add_headers("token" = tok))
    
    b <- fromJSON(rawToChar(a$content))
    
    df <- b$results
```

Comment: This is weird - it seems like the January and February data is missing for every year. Trying various permutations of the start and end dates produces the same issue no matter what year is tried, but all the other months are available. The data *does* seem to exist - the manual explorer finds it no problem: https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/datasets/GHCND/stations/GHCND:ASN00087036/detail

Comment: Thanks Dubukay for checking. Yes that's correct Jan and Feb always get missed for every year. I have tried changing multiple stations and different combinations of dates but somehow Jan, Feb months are problematic for some reason.